# Does my Controller object get instantiated and destroyed from memory for every Request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I just don't know if the Controller instance is existing in server memory for a certain period of time after the Request/Response or if it just appears in memory and disappears after each Request/Response. Or if it can depend on certain things, what does it depend on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Controller Lifecycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763775/asp-net-mvc-controller-lifecycle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DefaultControllerFactory` will indeed instantiate and destroy the controller instance for each request. (You can [browse the source yourself](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/23011#266459), or see Dino Esposito's article [Inside the ASP.NET MVC Controller Factory](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Inside-the-ASP-NET-MVC-Controller-Factory.aspx) for a tour.)