# How does ASP.NET MVC3 avoid multithreading bugs by sharing single instance of AsyncManager across Action invocations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to asp.net mvc3. i am trying to implement an async controller. because of limitations of our codebase, i am constrained to using mvc3 (cannot use mvc4). I see that mvc3 provides an `AsyncManager` class. let's say
Thread 0 creates instance of my controller and by extension instance of `AsyncManager`.

then the action method gets called concurrently:

**Thread 1:** t = 0s

```
public void ActionAsync()
{
   this.AsyncManager.Parameters["foo"] = "bar"; 
   // rest of code omitted - suppose it makes a http call to get some data
}
```

**Thread 2:** t = 0s

```
public void ActionAsync()
{
   this.AsyncManager.Parameters["foo"] = "spam"; // won't foo get overwritten?
   // rest of code omitted - suppose it makes a http call to get some data
}
```

Now when the completed method in response to the first call to `ActionAsync` gets called after 1s:

**Thread 3:** t = 1s

```
public ActionResult ActionCompleted(string foo)
{
   // won't foo become corrupted here?

}
```

i thought a unique instance of `AsyncManager` should be created and associated per call to an Action method, but looks like asp.net mvc3 creates an instance of `AsyncManager` per controller instance. how can it use same instance across concurrent action invocations?

**Another situation**: Thread 1 calls `ActionAsync` and makes a http call in that method and increments `AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations`. Simultaneously Thread 2 calls `ActionAsync` and makes a http call and increments `AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations`. after 1 s, first http call completes and `AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations` is decremented - but the `ActionCompleted` method will not get called since `AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations` will not be zero. clearly i am missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like i found answer to my question. A new instance of controller is created for every request per these links:
[ASP.NET MVC: Is Controller created for every request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425920/asp-net-mvc-controller-created-for-every-request)
[ASP.NET MVC Controller Lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763775/asp-net-mvc-controller-lifecycle)

so there is a separate `AsyncManager` per call to an Action method.